# Can not find function implementation React js

Tags: reactjs

I am a complete beginner in React development.

Currently, I am learning about functional component.

Here is my APP.JS file

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import  Greeto from './Component/Greet';
import  grt from './Component/grt';
import Welcome from './Component/Welcome';
import zxc from './Component/zxc';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <zxc />
     <Greeto />
        <Welcome/>
       
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here `Greeto` and `Welcome` Function are working fine but not `zxc` function (i am neither  receiving any output from it nor any error its just blank.

Here is 'zxc' implementation

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
    
     
function zxc (){
    return <h1>good morning</h1>
}
    
export default zxc;
```

Everything seems in the right order is there anything caching related stuff which might  be causing it.

I am using VScode for this.

Comment: You imported app into zxc, and then zxc into app. i'm guessing that circular is why it didn't function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'z' in zxc needs to be in caps.

Answer (score 3):

Your functional components must start with a uppercase letter.

> use Zxc